# Как найти текст с переносами строк между двумя маркерами

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Текст может быть любой. Например

```
>>
текст текст
ds aihdO#U$(20
<<
```

Надо удалить всё что между `>>` и `<<` включая сами маркеры.
Я пытался с этим регулярным выражением: `>>((.|\n)+?)<<`, но у меня получилось `<re.Match object; span=(67, 206), match='Что сделать потом: Комментарии [СДЕЛАНО 2>` (даже без закрывающей кавычки)

Сам текст:

```
>> Что сделать потом:
Комментарии [СДЕЛАНО 2/2 (90%) Нужно исправить комментарии]
Переменные [СДЕЛАНО 0%]
Input [СДЕЛАНО 0%] <<
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Вы можете упростить регулярное выражение до `>>.*?<<`, но используйте опцию `s`,
- чтобы убедиться, что захватывается всё, что надо, выводите `.group()` — это весь захват.

```py
import re
text = r'''
>> Что сделать потом:
Комментарии [СДЕЛАНО 2/2 (90%) Нужно исправить комментарии]
Переменные [СДЕЛАНО 0%]
Input [СДЕЛАНО 0%] <<
'''

pattern = r'>>.*?<<'

for match in re.finditer (pattern, text, re.S):
    print (match.group())
```